# Least Recently Used (LRU) Cache

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I know that I can use various container classes in STL but it's an overkill and expensive for this purpose.

We have over 1M+ users online and per user we need to maintain 8 unrelated 32-bit data items. The goal is to

1. find if an item exists in the list,
2. if not, insert. Remove oldest entry if full.

Brute Force approach would be to maintain a last write pointer and iterate (since only 8 items) but I am looking for inputs to better analyze and implement.

Look forward to some interesting suggestions in  terms of design pattern and algorithm.

Comment: `C` or `C++`? The answer may vary significantly...

Comment: Don't bother. 1M users * 8 field/user * 4 Bytes/field = 32 MBytes. On a decent server processor relevant data will be in L3 cache all the time. Any algorithm is an overkill. Write a clean, simple, maintainable code and move on. Better spend time (that you would waste on premature optimizations) on implementing another feature for your users.

Comment: I recommend a simple array with linear search for the items (and align items to 32-byte boundary, so it never crosses a cache-line). Store items in arrival order, if it is full, then remove the first and shift. I don't think that any complex algorithm will be significantly faster.

Comment: You may want to clarify a few details. I assume you mean "oldest data item out of the 8 for the given user". And I don't know whether you want the age of the insertion, or the age of the last lookup. LR**U** suggests the latter but your suggested implementation is the former.

Comment: @drop thanks, I agree. Our current implementation uses linear array but was exploring if there are better possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Don Knuth gives several interesting and very efficient approximations in *The Art of Computer Proramming.*

1. Self-organizing list I: when you find an entry, move it to the head of the list; delete from the end.
2. Self-organizing list II: when you find an entry, move it up one spot; delete from the end.

   [Both the above in Vol. 3 §6.1(A).]
3. Another scheme involves maintaining the list circularly with 1 extra bit per entry, which is set when you find that entry, and cleared when you skip past it to find something else. You always start searching at the last place you stopped, and if you don't find the entry you replace the one with the next clear bit with it, i.e. it hasn't been used since one entire trip around the list.

   [Vol. 1 §2.5(G).]

Answer (score 1):

You want to use here a combination of a `Hash` table and a `doubly linked list`.
Each item is accessible via the hash table that holds the key you need plus a pointer to the element in the list.

**Algorithm:**

Given new item `x`, do:
1. Add `x` to the head of the list, save pointer as `ptr`.
2. Add `x` to the hash table where the data is stored, and add `ptr`.
3. If the list is bigger than allowed, take the last element (from the tail of the list) and remove it. Use the key of this element to remove it from the Hash table as well.

Comment: Not sure that this will be faster than a brute force linear search and shift, as it's only 8 32 bit items.

Comment: Thanks, however as I mentioned, any list or map would be overkill for 8 entries and will not be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a C implementation of LRU cache try this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lru-cache-implementation/)

The idea is that we use two data structures to implement an LRU Cache.

Queue which is implemented using a doubly linked list. The maximum size of the queue will be equal to the total number of frames available (cache size).The most recently used pages will be near front end and least recently pages will be near rear end. 
A Hash with page number as key and address of the corresponding queue node as value. 
When a page is referenced, the required page may be in the memory. If it is in the memory, we need to detach the node of the list and bring it to the front of the queue. 
If the required page is not in the memory, we bring that in memory. In simple words, we add a new node to the front of the queue and update the corresponding node address in the hash. If the queue is full, i.e. all the frames are full, we remove a node from the rear of queue, and add the new node to the front of queue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Cuckoo's Filter](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf) which is a *probabilistic data structure* that supports fast [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) membership testing. It is a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)-based data structure.

Time Complexity of Cuckoo's Filter:

1. Lookup: *O(1)*
2. Deletion: *O(1)*
3. Insertion: *O(1)*

---

For reference here is how the cuckoo filter works.

```
Parameters of the filter

 1. Two Hash Functions: h1 and h2
 2. An array B with n Buckets. The i-th Bucket will be called B[i]

Input : L, a list of elements to inserted into the cuckoo filter.

Algorithm:
while L is not empty:
    Let x be the 1st item in the list L. Remove x from the list.
    if (B[h1(x)] == empty)
          place x in B[h1(x)];
    else if (B[h2(x)] == empty)
          place x in B[h2(x)];
    else
          Let y be the element in B[h2(x)]
          Prepend y to L
          place x in B[h2(x)]
```

For LRU you can use time stamping in your hash function by keeping just a local variable.

This is the best approach for very large data sets to date.

Comment: Given that there are only O(8) entries per user, all operations are O(1) anyway. This is not a very large data set, not at all.

Comment: @MSalters per user has 8 entries, and the question said there are more than 1M users, so there are 8 x 1M entries. so that's why I think it has a large data set

Comment: Then your answer is unclear. Do you propose to store 8 million entries in a single Cuckoo Filter? That's certainly possible, you just give user XYZ the entries XYZ-0 to XYZ-7. And you can timestamp each of them to figure out which of the 8 entries is the oldest, and would need to be replaced. However, this is far from efficient. The memory overhead is enormous, and locality of reference is entirely absent.

Comment: Thanks Sahib. There are 1M users and they are already in hash map, so once we get user entry, we only need to manage these 8 entries.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would either go with the self organising lists as proposed by EJP or, as we only have eight elements, simply store them together with a timestamp sequentially.

When accessing an element, just update the timestamp, when replacing, replace the one with oldest timestamp (one linear search). This is less efficient on replacements, but more efficient on access (no need to move any elements around). And it might be the easiest to implement...

Modification of self organising lists, if based on some array data structure: Sure, on update, you have to shift several elements (variant I) or at least swap two of them (variant II) - but if you organize the data as ring buffer, on replacement we just replace the last element with the new one and move the buffer's pointer to this new element:

```
a, b, c, d
      ^
```

Accessing a:

```
d, b, a, c
      ^
```

New element e:

```
d, e, a, c
   ^
```

Special case: accessing the oldest element (d in this case) - we then simply can move the pointer, too:

```
d, e, a, c
^
```

Just: with only 8 elements, it might not be worth the effort to implement all this...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Drop and Geza's comments. The straightforward implementation will take one cache line read, and cause one cache line write.

The only performance question left is going to be the lookup and update of that 32 bit value in 256 bits. Assuming modern x86, the lookup itself can be two instructions: `_mm256_cmp_epi32_mask` finds all equal values in parallel, `_mm256_lzcnt_epi32` counts leading zeroes = number of older non-matching items*32. But even with older SIMD operations, the cache line read/write operations will dominate the execution time. And that's in turn is dominated by finding the right user. Which in turn is dominated by the network I/O involved.